# How to find a point a distance of d onwards, using angle and co-ordinates

Tags: ruby, geometry, game-physics, libgosu

(Using Ruby with Gosu)

I have a single-point object representing a man which looks in a certain direction.

I have three variables, `x`, `y` (the 2d co-ordinates of the man) and `@angle` (the direction he's facing, in degrees). If i want to find `x` and `y` of the point which is exactly a distance of `d` (let's make it 20) in front of the man (in otheenter code herer words in the direction he's facing), how do I compute this?

```
  def move
    # Move
    @x += @vel_x
    @y += @vel_y

    # HELP
    @point_in_front_of_me_x = # some_function_for_x(@x, @y, @angle)
    @point_in_front_of_me_y = # some_function_for_y(@x, @y, @angle)

    # Prevent window exit
    @x %= @window.width
    @y %= @window.height

    # Simulate air resistance
    @vel_x *= 0.95
    @vel_y *= 0.95
  end
```

If you know a Gosu library or a manual way, either will do. If you know both and can point out the benefits, that's even better!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the Gosu library (or the coordinate system it uses), but a manual solution would be to use trigonometry. You know the angle and the hypotenuse (`h`, the distance to move) of the triangle and you are trying to calculate the the x coordinate (length of the adjacent side, `b`) and y coordinate (length of the opposite side, `a`).

[image: triangle]

We can calculate `x_after_moving` (using a coordinate system centered on the man's current position - you should be able to easily adapt this to another coordinate system if you need) using the relation `sin(angle)=opposite/hypotenuse` and rearranging (we only have one unknown here, the opposite side (`b`)):

```
def x_after_moving(distance, angle)
  distance * Math.sin(angle * Math::PI / 180)
end
```

We're multiplying by pi/180 to convert from radians (what Ruby expects) to degrees. Similarly, knowing the relation `cos(angle)=adjacent/hypotenuse`, we can use a similar method to calculate the new y coord:

```
def y_after_moving(distance, angle)
  distance * Math.cos(angle * Math::PI / 180)
end
```

Verify that it works with the following:

```
p 'Angle 0 (straight up)'
p 'x:' + x_after_moving(20, 0).to_s + ', y:' + y_after_moving(20, 0).to_s
p 'Angle 90 (right)'
p 'x:' + x_after_moving(20, 90).to_s + ', y:' + y_after_moving(20, 90).to_s
```

Gives us:

```
"Angle 0 (straight up)"
"x:0.0, y:20.0"
"Angle 90 (right)"
"x:20.0, y:1.2246467991473533e-15"
```

You may get very small values instead of zero in some cases - rounding should solve this problem `y_after_moving(20, 90).round`.